# Ignore certain classes from dependency

Tags: quarkus

I have a dependency which contains both CDI and EBJ beans/classes, however in my Quarkus project I only use/inject the classes with CDI annotations. When specifying that dependency in my pom.xml and running Quarkus in dev-mode, I get numerous exceptions for classes that I don't use/inject in my project:

`Unsatisfied dependency for type <unused CDI class using/injecting EBJ bean>...`

I thought this was odd, since I thought that Quarkus only includes "used classes" into the packed jar. 
Then I realized that maybe the problem stem from "javax.ws.rs" annotations in the classes of the dependency.

---

Does Quarkus scan all dependencies for classes with JAX-RS annotations and includes those?

If yes, is there a way to define which classes or packages should be scanned for JAX-RS annotations?

If no, is there another way to exclude/ignore certain classes from a dependency? An option to generally exclude or ignore classes from dependencies would be very helpful for similar issues too (e.g. ambiguous dependency, etc).

Thanks!